# is a java scanner closed when an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception

If I have a method that throws FilenotFoundException because I am using a Scanner object to read a file, if the error actually gets thrown, does the scanner object get closed, or do I still have to do that when I handle the exception?

I know that when I use a try-catch-finally block write in my method to handle the exception, I close the  scanner object, but if I have to do it within a method in another object which catches the exception, I won't have access to the scanner object.

Please keep the explanations simple...obviously I am new to java (and OO in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using code like this
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/abc.txt"));` 
If it is throwing exception, `scanner` object it self will not be created, So no need to close it.

But the best way of coding is like below. you can close in finally block.

```
Scanner scanner=null;
try
{
    scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
    //your code here
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)//either catch or throw out
{
   //log it
}
finally
{
    if(null !=scanner)
    {
        scanner.close();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying `FileInputStream` will not even be opened if the file is not found when you do `new Scanner(File)`.

It is a good practice to close the scanner in the *finally* block. If the scanner is already closed, then the close call will have no effect.

Or you could try the `try-with-resources` construct which will automatically close resources if some exception occurs.

Comment: `try-with-resources` seems to be the best approach as it requires less code

Comment: @superbob it is the best approach for more reasons than just "less code" :).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you do this:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/file/does/not/exist"));
```

and the constructor throws `FileNotFoundException`.  The first thing to note is that the constructor *does not return a `Scanner` object*.  Instead the `new` expression will terminate abnormally, and the assignment to `scanner` won't happen.  Control will eventually end up in some handler for the exception, which won't be able to refer to `scanner` because it is out of scope.

So to answer your question:

> if the error actually gets thrown, does the scanner object get closed, or do I still have to do that when I handle the exception?

If `FileNotFoundException` is thrown by the constructor, there is no `Scanner` object to `close()` ... so you don't need to close it.

However, depending on how you wrote the code, you may reach a handler or a `finally` block without knowing whether an exception was thrown at all, whether it was thrown in the constructor, or after the constructor completed.  The way to deal with this depends on which version of Java you are using.  Prior to Java 7, the idiom is something like @Sangeeth's answer.  For Java 7 and later you can write this:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
    //your code here
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //log it
}
```

Note that the "try-with-resources" syntax has an implicit `finally` that automatically calls `close()` on each of the (autocloseable) resources declared at the start of the `try`.  This absolves you of responsibility for the fiddly code that closes the resources in the various possible success and failure cases.

---

In fact, we can take this a level deeper.  The `Scanner` constructor calls `FileInputStream` to open the file, and that is where the FileNotFoundException would be thrown.  In turn, this will call through to the native `open` method to actually open the file.  If something goes wrong in this process (and an exception is thrown), then it is the constructors' responsibility to ensure that any resources are freed (e.g. native streams are closed) before allowing the exception to propagate.

It has to work that way, because the failed constructors don't return anything, and they can't rely on something further up the stack knowing how to release resources in a specific exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should close scanner object in **finally** block irrespective you catch exception or not.